# Referring from the "many" field to the "one" in Django

Tags: django, django-models

A noob question.
I have followed the official Django tutorial and I have the following:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I have tried replacing the Choice.**str**() code as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Choice for Q: {}'.format(Question.objects.get(pk=self.question_id_id).__str__())
```

I am trying to view the question related to this choise (when viewed in the admin).
The code doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `self.question`?

Comment: This could be clarified if you try some of these things in the Django shell. If you load up a Choice object, call it `c`, you can call `print(c.question)` to see what happens. You can also try `print(c.question_id_id)`, which should result in an error, and `print(c.question_id)`, which should result in the ID of the related question, a.k.a. `c.question.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to do an extra query inside the **str** method.
Secondly, the string formatting needs a string. You are passing a Question object's **str** method, that is you're basically passing a reference for this function object (Yes, everything is an object in python)

This snippet should solve your issue.

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Choice for Q: {}'.format(str(self.question.id))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. It did need an extra ')' at the end. The reason I couldn't see this simple answer before is that I added the following line in the __str__ function:
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
Then I tried to print the available fields in 'self' by typing: pp self.__dict__
that gave me:
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001E565FCBFD0>,
 'choice_text': 'Everything',
 'id': 2,
 'question_id': 1,
 'votes': 0}
So I couldn't see how the Choice will refer back to the question. It seems I was over complicating a simple issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Choice for Q: {}'.format(self.question.__str__())
```

Comment: You don't need the last `.__str__()`